add customize line header not smooth connected
I would like to add a line and a arrow as head of line like below. it works basically but the connection between the added line and arrows not smooth.
I guess I need some thing like --cycle to make the connection smooth but not sure how I can do it.
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{open arr}{open arr}
{\pgfarrowsleftextend{+0pt}\pgfarrowsrightextend{+0.5\pgflinewidth}}
{
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{.5*\pgflinewidth-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5*\pgfutil@tempdimb+.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{-.5*\pgfutil@tempdimb-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%  
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{10pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10pt}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-10pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%  
  %\pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{open line}{open line}
{\pgfarrowsleftextend{+0pt}\pgfarrowsrightextend{0pt}}
{
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{.5*\pgflinewidth-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5*\pgfutil@tempdimb+.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{-.5*\pgfutil@tempdimb-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%  
  %\pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
    \draw[double distance=5,
      open line-open arr,
      line width=5,      
      shorten >=10pt,
      shorten <=0pt] (B) to[in=45,out=135] (A);
    \foreach \x in {A,B} {
      \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1] at (\x) {};
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Output:


Arrowsheads on curved lines are always a bit off.  The line is shortened and the arrowhead is added as a straight segment.  I would start with the arrowhead and work backward.

Can you explain what you mean by “not smooth”? While I see some things I don't like (both ends don't exactly lie on the red dots and the right side has same empty corners) I'm not sure we see the same things. By the way, you're using a very old syntax of implementing arrow tips. Whether the new one is better I don't know.

For example, using \pgfarrowsdeclare{open line}{open line}{\pgfarrowsleftextend{.25*(\pgflinewidth-\pgfinnerlinewidth)}\pgfarrowsrightextend{.25*(\pgflinewidth-\pgfinnerlinewidth)}}{\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgflinewidth}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}\pgfsetlinewidth{.5*(\pgflinewidth-\pgfinnerlinewidth)}\pgfusepathqstroke} for the open line makes the right side look, in my opinion good. The other side needs some more math to figure out.

Ultimately, I think for big arrow tips, simply drawing a white shortened lines on top of the normal line including the bending library and a sep instead of the shorten keys will lead to nicer looking lines.
Here are two arrow tips, namely

Double Cap which just ends the line with a bar and
Double Stealth which draws an open Stealth arrow tip.

Due to bug #896 using the bending library on doubled lines will lead to arrow tips that are misplaced. This is why I'm using the quick key to disable the bending library's action in case it gets loaded.
Unfortunatly, this will lead to a misformed curved line which is more noticeable the bigger the tip.
In the picture below, I let TikZ draw the proper curve in gray on top of the misformed curve.
Luckily, the Double Cap tip is barely effected by this.
Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.arrows}
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = Double Cap@,
  defaults = {length = +0pt +1 +1, width = +0pt +1 +0},
  setup code={%
    \pgfarrowssettipend{+0pt}%
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{+-\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{+-.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{+0pt}{+.5\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{+-\pgfarrowlength}{+.5\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength},
  drawing code={%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \ifpgfarrowroundcap\pgfsetroundcap\fi
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
      {\dimexpr.5\pgfarrowwidth\ifpgfarrowroundcap-.5\pgfarrowlength\fi}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
      {\dimexpr-.5\pgfarrowwidth\ifpgfarrowroundcap+.5\pgfarrowlength\fi}}%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{+\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfusepathqstroke},
  parameters={\the\pgfarrowlength,\the\pgfarrowwidth,\ifpgfarrowroundcap c\fi}}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = Double Stealth@, clone = Stealth,
  append setup code = {%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\lwocenter
      {.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth+.25*(\pgflinewidth-\pgfinnerlinewidth)}%
    \advance\pgfarrowinset by\pgf@yc % undo weird things
    \ifdim\pgfarrowinset=0pt \def\shortenedinset{0pt}%
    \else \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\shortenedinset
      {\pgfarrowinset/\pgfutil@tempdimb*(\pgfutil@tempdimb-\lwocenter)}\fi
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{\shortenedinset}%
    \pgfarrowssave\lwocenter
    \pgfarrowssave\shortenedinset},
  drawing code = {%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin\pgfsetroundjoin\else\pgfsetmiterjoin\fi
    \ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
      \else\pgfsetlinewidth{+\pgfarrowlinewidth}\fi
    \ifdim\shortenedinset=0pt
      \pgfsetrectcap
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\shortenedinset}{-\lwocenter}}%
    \else
      \pgfsetbuttcap
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint
        {\shortenedinset\advance\pgf@x-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{-\lwocenter}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\shortenedinset}{-\lwocenter}}%
    \fi
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@ya}{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgf@x by\pgf@ya}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@ya}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\shortenedinset}{\lwocenter}}%
    \ifdim\shortenedinset=0pt \else
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint
        {\shortenedinset\advance\pgf@x-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{\lwocenter}}%
    \fi
    \ifpgfarrowopen \pgfusepathqstroke\else
      \ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth>0pt \pgfusepathqfillstroke
                             \else \pgfusepathqfill \fi \fi}}%
\makeatother
\pgfdeclarearrow{name = Double Cap,     means = {Double     Cap@[quick]}}
\pgfdeclarearrow{name = Double Stealth, means = {Double Stealth@[open, quick]}}
\pgfdeclarearrow{name = Double Triangle,
  means={Double Stealth[inset=+0pt, angle=+60:+2.7pt +3.6 +.75]}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  scale=2,
  arr 0/.style={arrows={Double Stealth}-{Double Cap},
            postaction={draw, help lines, -}},
  arr 1/.style={arrows={Double Stealth[fill=white]}-{Double Cap}},
  arr 2/.style={double=red, arrows={Double Stealth[fill=red]}-{Double Cap}},
  arr 3/.style={arrows={Double Triangle[round]}-{Double Cap[round]}},
  arr 4/.style={arrows={Double Triangle[round, fill=white]}-{Double Cap[round]}},
  arr 5/.style={double=red, arrows={[round]},
                arrows={Double Triangle[angle=+90:+15pt, fill=red]}-{Double Cap}}]
\foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
  \draw[double distance=5pt, line width=+2pt, arr \i]
    (2,-\i0 pt) to[in=45,out=135] (0,-\i0 pt);
\end{document}

Output


Very nice arrows!

awesome, I saw a little grey line at the arrow header. not sure if it's possible to remove it.

@lucky1928 Yes, that's a common visual render problem with many PDF viewers. This is why the second and second to last example use fill=white with the arrow tip to hide it.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. The mentioned bug – which I already forgot about – is really unfortunate, though. :(

Different approach: draw two arrows above each other
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \draw[->,line width=0.3cm,color=black,arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:0.5cm]}] (B) to[in=45,out=135] (A);
    \draw[->,line width=0.1cm,color=white,arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:0.25cm]},shorten <=0.1cm,shorten >=0.1cm] (B) to[in=45,out=135] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



(I drafted up something similar with a postaction but it was difficult to generalize this.) If you load the bending library and use the sep arrow key instead of the shortening, you'll get much nicer (and parallel) lines: arrows = {_[sep=.1cm]-Stealth[inset=0pt, sep=.1cm, angle=90:0.25cm]}

@Qrrbrbirlbel I'd love to see an answer from you with the bending library!

OP already did implement the postaction approach but stayed with the Stealh/angle combination which makes it easier: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/722369
