modify shorten value for inner draw command
To generate a big arrow with white background inside, below code try to draw a small arrow in style define.
If the outside shorten value is 0, then current logic works fine, but if define a 5pt shorten value in the outside arrow, current logic not work since it always use 1pt as inside arrow's shorten value.
What's proper way to read the shorten value in inside arrow and substract 1pt for the inside arrow (white background).
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  double arrow/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:10]},
    ,line width=#1,#2, % first arrow
    postaction={draw,-stealth,#3,line width={#1-1pt},
          arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:{10-2*1pt}]},
                shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt/sqrt(2)}, % second arrow
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  \draw[double arrow=7pt colored by black and white,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt] (0,-.1) arc(120:60:.5) arc(-120:-60:.5) -- ++(30:.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Output:


What happens is that postaction is independent of the properties that you add later, if you want them to affect what is in postaction you must do it through an additional variable, in this case I added #4 for shorten, also for defining the size of the arrow vartiable #1 needs to be involved in its size, since changing the scale is counterproductive.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        x=1cm,
        y=1cm,
        double arrow/.style args={#1 colored #2 and #3 shorten #4}{
            arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:#1]},
            line width=#1,
            #2, % first arrow
            shorten <=#4,
            shorten >=#4,
            postaction={
                draw,
                %-stealth, %<-this line has no effect
                #3,
                line width={#1-1pt},
                arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:{#1-1.75pt}]},
                shorten <=#4+0.5pt,
                shorten >=#4+1pt/sqrt(2)
            }
        },
        scale=1,
        transform shape
    ]
    \node[draw,circle](a) at (0,0){A};
    \node[draw,circle](b) at (5,1){B};
    \draw[double arrow=0.1cm colored blue and white shorten 0] (a) .. controls +(90:2) and +(135:3) .. (b);
    \draw[double arrow=0.2cm colored red and white shorten 0.1cm] (a) .. controls +(45:2.5) and +(-135:2.5) .. (b);
    \draw[double arrow=0.4cm colored green and white shorten 0.5cm] (a) .. controls +(-45:3) and +(-90:3) .. (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

